# Nested CloudKit queries and UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, cloudkit

I am trying to make a simple table-based app using `CloudKit` that allows you to drill down to find more information about a particular item. Let's say my app shows a directory of shops located inside theme parks, divided by sections of the park.

In my initial table view, I was able to get the list of ThemeParks. Tapping on a ThemePark drills down to another table view that has section header titles for each section of the park. I was able to query for the Sections that had a `CKReference` matching the chosen ThemePark. The problem occurs when I try to get the Shops that match each Section. I have no clue how to wait until the shops are all downloaded before reloading the table view. Here is some sample code from my view controller:

```
func getSectionsFromCloud() {
    let cloudContainer = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
    let publicDatabase = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
    let recordToMatch = CKReference(recordID: themePark.recordID, action: CKReferenceAction.DeleteSelf)
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "themeParkOwner == %@", recordToMatch)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "ThemeParkSection", predicate: predicate)
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    query.sortDescriptors = [sort]
    self.publicDatabase.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil, completionHandler: {
        results, error in

        if error == nil {
            println("Successfully retrieved sections")
            self.sections = results as [CKRecord]
            for section in self.sections {
                self.getShopsFromCloud(section)
            }

        } else {
            println(error)
        }
    })
}
```

And here is my `getShopsFromCloud` function:

```
func getShopsFromCloud(record:CKRecord) {
    let cloudContainer = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
    let publicDatabase = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
    let recordToMatch = CKReference(recordID: record.recordID, action:CKReferenceAction.DeleteSelf)
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "sectionOwner == %@", recordToMatch)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Shop", predicate: predicate)
    self.publicDatabase.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil, completionHandler: {
            results, error in

        if error == nil {
            println("Successfully retrieved shops.")
            self.shops.append(results as [CKRecord])

        } else {
            println(error)
        }
    })
}
```

The problem is, `getSectionsFromCloud()` finishes before all of the `getShopsFromCloud()` calls. So if I reload the table view in the completionHandler for getSectionsFromCloud, it won't show the shops. However, if I reload the table view in the `completionHandler` for `getShopsFromCloud`, every time the query is executed (which is once for each section), `numberOfRowsInSection` also gets called once for each section. So if my `numberOfRowsInSection` is this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.shops[section].count
}
```

...I get a "fatal error: array index out of range" error, because the first array of shops are downloaded, but `numberOfRowsInSection` is then called for the second array, which isn't there yet. So how can I know when `getShopsFromCloud()` finishes and where in the world do I put that `tableView.reloadData()` call?

Comment: Well, you need to take a look at GCD - Using Dispatch Groups.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: take a look at this tutorial to understand how it works: http://www.raywenderlich.com/79150/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-part-2. In your case you need to create a dispatch group that will download sections, then when it's done, you will update sections with rows and reload table view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use dependencies between fetch requests and add them to the Queue of the Database object (`CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicDatabase().addOperation`) instead of calling the convenience method

Comment: This ended up being the easiest-to-understand solution for a newbie like me! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to solve this is to create the self.shops array at the same moment you are creating the self.sections array. just make sure that each self.shops item also contains an empty array. That way the count will return 0 because the list has not been fetched yet. Doing the reloaddata inside the getShopsFromCloud is the right way to do it. You do have to be aware that you need to execute the reloaddata on the main queue.